# how to call the BroadcastReceiver during boot time?

Tags: javascript, android

pleas any one help me i am new in android development. i want to call the broadcastreciver during boot time. but its not working.here is my source code

**i given the permission of manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tajmirkhan.broadcasetreciver_new">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Bootservice" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="500">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**and this one is my broadcastreceiver class**

```
public class Bootservice extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("dd","above the onReceive mthode");
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "boot completed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("dd","inisde the onReceive mthode");
        }
    }
}
```

> this is my mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("dd","oncreat ");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to call `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>` just add line to your receiver

```
<receiver 
      android:name=".Bootservice" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
      <intent-filter android:priority="500">
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>

   </receiver>
```

this line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

indicates that when you press home button, your app will be listed as an option to launch the launcher home or your home activity (along with all the applications which have this category in their manifest for an activity). To be more simple, whenever you press the home button, all the applications installed in your phone which have CATEGORY.HOME category and Action_Main in intent-filter in their AndroidManifest.xml will be listed (unless you have chosen some application as default) in a chooser for the user to select which HOME they want to launch.

Happy coding!!

Comment: i applied this piece of code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a fix but try modifying:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
```

To:

```
if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
```